# New to CakePHP: Need help setting up error log

Tags: cakephp, error-logging

I'm new to CakePHP. I'm getting an internal server error in my app, but I haven't been able to locate my error log. I looked at the official docs, but I didn't find anything on what the log file is named or where I could find it. I'm not even sure whether error logging is enabled by default. Any help you can offer is appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Look in your **/app/tmp/logs/** folder, the file name should be **error.log**

I believe it is enabled by default, at least when debug is set to 2 in /app/Config/core.php.

```
Configure::write('debug', 2);
```

Comment: I changed the debug setting to 2 in core.php and tried it again, but I'm getting the same error and no error.log in /app/tmp/logs. I've checked write permissions on the /tmp folders, and it is enabled. I don't know why the error log won't appear.

Comment: Is your tmp directory writable? When setting up cakephp the default site has an indicator which tells you that. If it is, and still no error log available, Id suggest going for PHP errors log.

Comment: Or try doing `CakeLog::write('test','Hello world');` somewhere in your code. This should create test.log in the folder I told you about before. If the file is not created I believe it is because of tmp directory not being writable.

Comment: Sorry I missed that you already set the permissions on /tmp folder. However you might try creating a log manually anyways and see what happens. One more thing, if the error is reported by the server and not Cake there is a chance that Cakes logging didn't happen because the error aborted the script. Look for a PHP log then.